# Python and windows scheduler - run py script that invokes other scripts

Tags: python

I am trying to set up a windows scheduled task to run a python script that runs two other scripts. I use os package to do it with the code like below:

```
#mainScript.py
    import os
    
        os.system('script1.py 1')
        os.system('scripts.py 1')
```

The script works in a scheduled task except when I add the above code. What I mean If use script1.py in my bat file it works, but if I use the mainScript.py it gives me the error code.

```
'script1.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'script2.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I know I can just move all the code into **mainScript** but wonder if there is anything I can do to have.

Comment: You need to specify wich program will run the script, try this : os.system('python script1.py')

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify wich program will run the script.
Try this :

```
os.system('python script1.py')
```

Comment: In my case what actually worked was os.system('full path to python.exe' full path to the script1.py')

Comment: @Kalenji u do not need to specify full path is the path of python.exe is inside ENV variable.